# Maximum Ratio of White/Black pixels in an Edge Map

Tags: complexity-theory, artificial-intelligence, computer-vision

Is there a maximum possible ratio of white/black pixels in an edge map?

In my theoretical consideration all areas in an image which have the same intensity are black and only the edges are white. Hence, the white/black ratio must be theoretically smaller than 50/50 in any conceivable picture of our environment (In my opinion) as there are always areas with the same intensity and the edges cover these areas.

What I'm searching for is a theoretical upper limit for this ratio.

If I think about a 100x100 pixel array where e.g. every second line is a horizontal, vertical or both (checkerboard pattern) edge, I expect the  theoretical maximum ratio between white and black pixels to be 50/50?

Anyway, does anyone know if there is a mathematical proof, paper or source where this problem is described?

Comment: Can you define more formally when a coloring is legal in your case? That would be the first step toward a proof.

Comment: What is an edge map?  Also, what do you mean by an "edge"?  It's not clear what you mean by "all areas which have the same intensity must be black"; if you have a row of pixels that are all white, that sounds like an area that has the same intensity, so it's not clear how to interpret your question.

Comment: Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.  Please pick one site where you want the question to appear; delete the other copy; and edit the remaining question on that site to address all feedback received on both sites.  Thank you!

Comment: A formal description might be difficult. With 'edge map' I refer to a grey valued picture which is evaluated with an edge detection algorithm. I found a nice paper which yields an approach to edge detection in the field of topology: https://www.csc.univie.ac.at/paper/DonGraKanSch13.pdf    On page three there one can find a topological algorithm for edge detection. Further there are some example pics on page 6 which can clarify my questions a bit: the black/white ratio is always very low. I'm searching for a theoretical maximum for this problem.